# Animated transparent preloader image over a solid colored background

Tags: animation, transparency, animated-gif

I want to show a preloader on my website before the content loads,However when i choose a animated preloader image with transparent background the edges look very jagged. How to I modify the image or is there a way to have a transparent background to animated gifs?

I am using the preloaders from preloader.net

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first and probably easiest option you have is to use [spin.js](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js). “It dynamically creates spinning activity indicators that can be used as resolution-independent replacement for AJAX loading GIFs.”

---

If a script is not an option or you want to have a different spinner you have to create a .gif with no anti-aliasing that is bigger than the spinner you want to use and scale it down with html.

Original spinner without edges (without anti-aliasing, therefore it has a pixelated edge):

> [image]

But if this spinner gets scaled down, it looks nice:

> [image] [image]

Be sure to use

```
img {
    -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
}
```

to make it also look pretty in older IEs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a site that helps you generate your spinner. A great option is :
[loading.io](https://loading.io/asset/369109)